# Editing $PROFILE in Azure Cloud Shell

Tags: powershell, azure

I have setup Azure Cloud Shell, and put my profile script at default `$PROFILE` location, which appears to be `/home/username/.config/PowerShell/Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1`

However I noticed that only `/home/username/clouddrive` is persisted. So after some time, my profile is lost.

How can I have my profile persist, so I don't have to keep setting it up from time to time?

Or is there a way to make `$PROFILE` to point to some place in clouddrive and persist that setting?

Comment: It's best to run the shell on your local computer, whenever possible. Cloud Shell is a convenience tool but really isn't intended for long term use.

Comment: So is there no way to do this? My goal is to use some scripts when I'm out with only my phone. Which would help a lot if I can setup some aliases than having to type long commands on a touch keyboards.

Comment: You can always remote into your PC and the connect to the Azure VM instance.

Comment: Unfortunately that involves vpns and rdps and high data charges I don't want.

Comment: Neither ssh nor PowerShell remoting use any significant amount of bandwidth.

Comment: I mean, I can't remote into a shell at my work without rdp and I don't have a vm in azure for this case, only app service (plan)

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure OP long-ago figured this out, but I thought I would post the answer for newcomers wanting to revise their own PS profiles in the Azure Cloud Shell.  Just type "code ." and you get a basic editor based off of their open source Monaco editor (which is the core editor built-into VS Code).
Using this I edit my $PROFILE all the time.

More here:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-shell/using-cloud-shell-editor

Comment: Yea this works. but the issue is (was?, not sure if its still the case, since I moved on) that cloud shell discards your custom profile after some time. So you have to set it up all over from time to time.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Ah, yes there's now a persistent storage component you can have, was added to Cloud Shell some time back.  It helps.  So any Microsoft.Powershell_profie.ps1 placed there will persist & be processed on each subsequent fresh Azure Cloud PS session. 
 I've taken to using my local Azure Cloud Profile to simply load another "remote PS Profile" that I store over on a secret Gist I keep over on GitHub.  So whenever I need to edit/change things or add new Functions -- I do it there, and it follows me to all my Azure Cloud Shell sessions.